# Daemon for N autossh tunnels

Tags: ssh-tunnel, daemon

I use autossh to create a persistent tunnel from localhost to remotehost.

Starting autossh manually works fine, but if localhost reboots, the tunnel is gone. That's no surprise.

How to create a daemon to re-open around 20 tunnels after the reboot of localhost?

Server: Linux with systemd support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an systemd file to start an autossh daemon. In my case I would need create N such files:

```
[Unit]
Description=Keeps a tunnel to 'remote.example.com' open
After=network.target

[Service]
User=autossh
# -p [PORT]
# -l [user]
# -M 0 --> no monitoring
# -N Just open the connection and do nothing (not interactive)
# LOCALPORT:IP_ON_EXAMPLE_COM:PORT_ON_EXAMPLE_COM
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -N -q -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -p 22 -l autossh remote.example.com -L 7474:127.0.0.1:7474 -i /home/autossh/.ssh/id_rsa

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9707568

Comment: Just answered your other question: http://serverfault.com/a/730339/266218

Answer (score 1):

Add whatever command you normally run to `/etc/rc.local` and put an `&` on the end if it.

Answer (score 1):

We use `monit` to locally monitor/manage various processes on our servers. To manage `autossh` instances using `monit`, install the `monit` package and create a configuration file `/etc/monit/conf.d/autossh.conf`:

```
check process autossh1 pidfile "/tmp/autossh1.pid"
  start program = "/bin/bash -c 'export AUTOSSH_PIDFILE=/tmp/autossh1.pid; autossh -f user@host.example.com'" as uid user1 and group group1
  stop program = "/bin/bash -c 'kill `cat /tmp/autossh1.pid`'"
  group autossh
```

Then restart monit with `sudo service monit restart`.

If you want to run the process as root you can omit the `as uid user1 and group group1` at the end of the `start program =` line.

`monit` will periodically check if the process is running and will restart it if needed. You can display the status of processes managed by monit:

```
monit summary
```

You can also easily stop/start the process by running

```
monit stop autossh1
monit start autossh1
```

You can even create groups (as illustrated by the line `group autossh`) and then stop/start whole groups:

```
monit stop -g autossh
monit start -g autossh
```

By the way, the `monit` command line tool uses HTTP to communicate with the daemon. To make the communication work you need to include the following in `/etc/monit/monitrc`:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
    allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server
```

Hope that helps.