# Start N processes with one systemd service file

Tags: daemon, systemd

I found this systemd service file to start autossh to keep up a ssh tunnel: https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9707568

```
[Unit]
Description=Keeps a tunnel to 'remote.example.com' open
After=network.target

[Service]
User=autossh
# -p [PORT]
# -l [user]
# -M 0 --> no monitoring
# -N Just open the connection and do nothing (not interactive)
# LOCALPORT:IP_ON_EXAMPLE_COM:PORT_ON_EXAMPLE_COM
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -N -q -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -p 22 -l autossh remote.example.com -L 7474:127.0.0.1:7474 -i /home/autossh/.ssh/id_rsa

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Is there a way to configure systemd to start several tunnels in **one** service.

I don't want to create N system service files, since I want to avoid copy+paste.

All service files would be identical except "remote.example.com" would be replace with other host names.

## 1.5 year later ...

I asked this question roughly 1.5 year ago.

My mind has changed. Yes, it's nice, that you can do this with systemd, but I will use configuration-management in the future.

Why should systemd implement a template language and substitute %h? .. I think it makes no sense.

Several months later I think this looping and templating should be solved on a different level. I would use Ansible or TerraForm for this now.

Comment: In other words, you're saying use a configuration management system  to generate multiple almost identical service files to accomplish this task?  Hmmm, maybe.  As with most such matters, there's not a clear dividing line separating these.

Comment: @pgoetz config management is still new to me, but it has a benefit if you look at the topic of this question: If you look at the result of the config managment everybody who knows systemd service files will understand it:plain and simple service files. I think it makes more sense to learn and use a config management system since the knowledge can be used for all config in /etc, not just systemd.

Comment: I resorted to using Supervisor http://supervisord.org to define multiple processes in one file. Some repetition there stays, that's how I arrived here.

Comment: I wrote a SystemD service for SSH tunnels https://github.com/yurt-page/sshtunnel

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Well, assuming that the *only* thing changing per unit file is the `remote.example.com` part, you can use an [Instantiated](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html) [Service](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/getting-started-with-systemd.html#instantiated-units).

From the `systemd.unit` man page:

> Optionally, units may be instantiated from a template file at runtime.
>   This allows creation of multiple units from a single configuration
>   file. If systemd looks for a unit configuration file, it will first
>   search for the literal unit name in the file system. If that yields no
>   success and the unit name contains an "@" character, systemd will look
>   for a unit template that shares the same name but with the instance
>   string (i.e. the part between the "@" character and the suffix)
>   removed. Example: if a service getty@tty3.service is requested and no
>   file by that name is found, systemd will look for getty@.service and
>   instantiate a service from that configuration file if it is found.

Basically, you create a single unit file, which contains a variable (usually `%i`) where the differences occur and then they get linked when you "enable" that service.

For example, I have a unit file called `/etc/systemd/system/autossh@.service` that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=AutoSSH service for ServiceABC on %i
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=AUTOSSH_GATETIME=30 AUTOSSH_LOGFILE=/var/log/autossh/%i.log AUTOSSH_PIDFILE=/var/run/autossh.%i.pid
PIDFile=/var/run/autossh.%i.pid
#Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 40000 -NR 5000:127.0.0.1:5000 -i /opt/ServiceABC/.ssh/id_rsa_ServiceABC -l ServiceABC %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Which I've then enabled

```
[user@anotherhost ~]$ sudo systemctl enable autossh@somehost.example.com
ln -s '/etc/systemd/system/autossh@.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/autossh@somehost.example.com.service'
```

And can intereact with

```
[user@anotherhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start autossh@somehost.example.com
[user@anotherhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status autossh@somehost.example.com
autossh@somehost.example.service - AutoSSH service for ServiceABC on somehost.example
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/autossh@.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-10-20 13:19:01 EDT; 17s ago
 Main PID: 32524 (autossh)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-autossh.slice/autossh@somehost.example.com.service
           ├─32524 /usr/bin/autossh -M 40000 -NR 5000:127.0.0.1:5000 -i /opt/ServiceABC/.ssh/id_rsa_ServiceABC -l ServiceABC somehost.example.com
           └─32525 /usr/bin/ssh -L 40000:127.0.0.1:40000 -R 40000:127.0.0.1:40001 -NR 5000:127.0.0.1:5000 -i /opt/ServiceABC/.ssh/id_rsa_ServiceABC -l ServiceABC somehost.example.com

Oct 20 13:19:01 anotherhost.example.com systemd[1]: Started AutoSSH service for ServiceABC on somehost.example.com.
[user@anotherhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status autossh@somehost.example.com
[user@anotherhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status autossh@somehost.example.com
autossh@somehost.example.com.service - AutoSSH service for ServiceABC on somehost.example.com
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/autossh@.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2015-10-20 13:24:10 EDT; 2s ago
  Process: 32524 ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 40000 -NR 5000:127.0.0.1:5000 -i /opt/ServiceABC/.ssh/id_rsa_ServiceABC -l ServiceABC %i (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 32524 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 20 13:19:01 anotherhost.example.com systemd[1]: Started AutoSSH service for ServiceABC on somehost.example.com.
Oct 20 13:24:10 anotherhost.example.com systemd[1]: Stopping AutoSSH service for ServiceABC on somehost.example.com...
Oct 20 13:24:10 anotherhost.example.com systemd[1]: Stopped AutoSSH service for ServiceABC on somehost.example.com.
```

As you can see, all instances of `%i` in the unit file get replaced with `somehost.example.com`.

There's a bunch more [specifiers](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) that you can use in a unit file though, but I find `%i` to work best in cases like this.

Comment: Wow, systemd is great.

Comment: You don't show how to start automatically at boot, including of which ones to start.

Comment: With Systemd, the `enable` action is what makes a unit/service start at boot.

Comment: Can I  independently enable/disable the instances?

Comment: Yeah, that's what you're doing when you enable/disable them.

Comment: I can get this to work, but I'm required to have a log file. I tried with `StandardOutput=file:/path/to/log/file`, but it's only logging one instance at a time. Is this possible, or will the logging have to be in the script itself instead of the unit file?

Answer (score 32):

Here is a python example, which was what I was looking for. The `@` in the service filename lets you start N processes:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/my-worker@.service

[Unit]
Description=manages my worker service, instance %i
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=idle
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/virtualenvs/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=10
RestartSec=10
```

#### Various methods to call it

Enabling various counts for example:

- Enable 30 workers:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable my-worker\@{1..30}.service
  ```
- Enable 2 workers:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable my-worker\@{1..2}.service
  ```

Then be sure to reload:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now you can start/stop then in various ways:

- Start 1:

  ```
  sudo systemctl start my-worker@2.service
  ```
- Start Multiple:

  ```
  sudo systemctl start my-worker@{1..2}
  ```
- Stop Multiple:

  ```
  sudo systemctl stop my-worker@{1..2}
  ```
- Check status:

  ```
  sudo systemctl status my-worker@1
  ```

**UPDATE**: To manage instances as one service, you can do something like this:

/etc/systemd/system/some-worker@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=manage worker instances as a service, instance %i
Requires=some-worker.service
Before=some-worker.service
BindsTo=some-worker.service

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=idle
User=root
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/profile.d/optional_envvars.sh
ExecStart=/usr/local/virtualenvs/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py
TimeoutStartSec=10
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=some-worker.service
```

/usr/bin/some-worker-start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl start some-worker@{1..10}
```

/etc/systemd/system/some-worker.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=manages some worker instances as a service, instance

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh /usr/bin/some-worker-start.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And now you can manage all instances with `sudo systemctl some-worker (start|restart|stop)`

Here is some boilerplate for your `script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging


def worker_loop():
    shutdown = False
    while True:

        try:
            if shutdown:
                break

            # Your execution logic here.
            # Common logic - i.e. consume from a queue, perform some work, ack message
            print("hello world")

        except (IOError, KeyboardInterrupt):
            shutdown = True
            logging.info("shutdown received - processing will halt when jobs complete")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception("unhandled exception on shutdown. {}".format(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker_loop()
```

Comment: @radek: Two things I do not understand: First, %i is only used in the description of the unit file. How does the start command know what to start? Second, how does `systemctl some-worker (start|restart|stop)` know which instances to work on?

Comment: %i is the output from @ in the name of the service file. Second part is already explained in the answer, see `Now you can start/stop then in various ways`.

Comment: I think his answer is incomplete without the scripts being involved. Most "magic" is done inside the scripts which are missing.

Comment: I have provided a full working solution here actually. Which "scripts" are you referring to? /path/to/my/script.py can be whatever you want, a "hello world" if you want. Something that will stay up running until it receives a kill signal. Please note the question is not specific to python.

Comment: Wow it lets you start multiples at a time? mind blown...

Comment: @radtek, how does this work say if one of the instance was masked or disabled? I want to restart all instances except the ones that were masked/disabled. Thanks.

Comment: @D.prd not sure but try it and let me know how it works. I assume the disabled service wouldn't start if its disabled.

Comment: @radtek yes, I tested it out. The masked instance won't start (which is correct) but the parent service (some-worker in your example) shows a status failure even though all dependent units except the masked one are restarted successfully. Is it possible for the parent service (some-worker.service) to report a failure only and only if *all* of its dependent %i instances fail? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

GregL's answer helped me a great deal. Here is an example of a unit template I used in my code using the example above for a gearman job server. I made a shell script that lets me create X amount of "workers" using this one template.

```
[Unit]
Description=az gearman worker
After=gearman-job-server.service

[Service]
PIDFile=/var/run/gearman_worker_az%i.pid
Type=simple
User=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/mysite.com/jobs/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f gearman_worker_az.php > /dev/null 2>&1
Restart=on-success
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score -1):

I have searched for solution to a similar task and actually have found one, that i believe is easier to accomplish, but is supposed to be [hacky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516749/how-best-to-start-my-systemd-service-to-run-multiple-apps). *(and is not mentioned here)*

> I needed to create multiple ssh connections after vpn creates a tunnel,
> so i have created a service that is dependent on tun device and calls
> shell script with appropriate commands.

Service /etc/systemd/system/ssh_tunnel.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Reverse SSH Service to access hidden services
ConditionPathExists=|/usr/bin
Wants=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device
After=network.target sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/openvpn/ssh_tunnels.sh 
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=0
GuessMainPID=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/openvpn/ssh_tunnels.sh:

```
!/bin/bash
#sleep 15

echo 'Tunelling some ports'
killall -HUP ssh

su - user -c 'ssh -f admin@172.171.1.1 -p 9999 -L :3690:svn.newbox.ru:3690 -L :8888:10.1.20.55:80 -L :8181:10.1.10.10:80 -N -vvv'

ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -f admin@172.171.1.1 -p 9999 -L :587:mail.domain.ru:587 -L :995:mail.newbox.ru:995 -L :22:10.1.2.1:22 -N -vvv &

exit 0
```

Result:

```
# systemctl status ssh_tunnel.service
● ssh_tunnel.service - Reverse SSH Service to access hidden services
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ssh_tunnel.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-03-20 16:01:07 UTC; 22min ago
    Process: 156 ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/openvpn/ssh_tunnel.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
     Memory: 3.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh_tunnel.service
             ├─166 ssh -f admin@172.171.1.1 -p 9999 -L :3690:svn.newbox.ru:3690 -L :8888:10.1.20.55:80 ->
             └─168 ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -f admin@172.171.1.1 -p 9999 -L :587:mail.newbox.ru:5>
...
```

However, i haven't checked yet, how it survives vpn restart, but it's another topic.