# Creating an instance service file using an ansible template

Tags: ansible, systemd, ansible-playbook

I have been using ansible for a while to install and configure several services, but this is the first time I am trying to set up a service that can have multiple instances running at the same time. I'm using a template for the service file, something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/service/api
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -O /var/lib/service/api/main.py -f /var/lib/service/api/cfg/service_api.cfg -p {{ port }}
Type=simple
```

And then my role for installing and configuring this service contains tasks like this:

```
- name: Configure api.service
  template: src=api.service.j2 dest=/etc/systemd/system/api@{{port}}.service

- name: Start service
  systemd: name=api@{{port}} state=restarted enabled=yes
```

Right now this is working for something like port = 80, but I don't think I made it generic enough. I don't fully understand how to create these instance services. How can I modify the service file and the role such that each listening port can have its own service file? Should I use the "Wants" keyword, or something like "WantedBy=multi-user.target"?

Comment: This doesn't look like an instantiated unit. I don't see `%i` or `%I` anywhere in it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. It runs fine as is right now, but I want to convert it to an instantiated unit, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rename your local file to **`api@.service`** (not `api.service.j2`) — we'll be using systemd templating instead of ansible's Jinja2 templating. Then change it like below:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service on port %i
[Service]
...
ExecStart=... -p %i
...
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you should be able to use it with ansible  with a  playbook like the following one:

```
- name: Deploy api@.service
  copy: src=api@.service dest=/etc/systemd/system/

- name: Start service
  systemd: name=api@{{item}} state=restarted enabled=yes
  with_items:
    - 80
```

*(Though I'm not sure if it's better to use `systemd` or `service` module here; I'm still a newbie with ansible.)*

**See also: https://serverfault.com/a/730339/74509**